# Zend Authentication where user role stored in separate db table

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have a User table where  userID, username and password are stored and a Role table which contains user role . To link these two tables, I have a table (user_role) which contains userID and roleID. How can I use Zend Auth to authenticate users and use Zend Acl to control user access.  [This is the database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687165/feedback-on-school-management-system-database-design)

Comment: @TimFountain I am following zf_turoial on YouTube. the problem is that the instant of Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable requires a db table. This table need to have a column that stores user role but in my database the user role is in a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Zend_Auth adapter that works with whatever structure your application has.

Here is an example of an Auth adapter that uses my entity models and mappers to provide the credentials and user data for authentication.

```
<?php

/**
 * Description of Auth_Adapter
 *
 */
class Auth_Adapter implements Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface
{
    /**
     * The username
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $identity = null;
    /**
     * The password
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $credential = null;
    /**
     * Users database object
     *
     * @var Model_Mapper_Abstract
     */
    protected $usersMapper = null;

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param Model_Mapper_Abstract $userMapper
     */
    public function __construct($username, $password, Model_Mapper_Abstract $userMapper = null)
    {
        if (!is_null($userMapper)) {
            $this->setMapper($userMapper);
        } else {
            $this->usersMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_User();
        }
        $this->setIdentity($username);
        $this->setCredential($password);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Zend_Auth_Result
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        // Fetch user information according to username
        $user = $this->getUserObject();

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(
                    Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND,
                    $this->getIdentity(),
                    array('Invalid username')
            );
        }
        // check whether or not the hash matches using my own password class
        $check = Password::comparePassword($this->getCredential(), $user->password);
        if (!$check) {
            return new Zend_Auth_Result(
                    Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID,
                    $this->getIdentity(),
                    array('Incorrect password')
            );
        }
        // Success!
        return new Zend_Auth_Result(
                Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS,
                $this->getIdentity(),
                array()
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param type $userName
     * @return \Auth_Adapter
     */
    public function setIdentity($userName)
    {
        $this->identity = $userName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param type $password
     * @return \Auth_Adapter
     */
    public function setCredential($password)
    {
        $this->credential = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param type $mapper
     * @return \Auth_Adapter
     */
    public function setMapper($mapper)
    {
        $this->usersMapper = $mapper;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return object
     */
    private function getUserObject()
    {
        return $this->getMapper()->findOneByColumn('name', $this->getIdentity());
    }

    /**
     * @return object
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        $object = $this->getUserObject();
        $array = array(
            'id'   => $object->id,
            'name' => $object->name,
            'role' => $object->role
        );
        return (object) $array;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdentity()
    {
        return $this->identity;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCredential()
    {
        return $this->credential;
    }

    /**
     * @return object Model_Mapper_Abstract
     */
    public function getMapper()
    {
        return $this->usersMapper;
    }
}
```

You could also extend any of the current adapters to provide the functionality you need.

Good Luck!